# overwriting the values of a column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to modify each string present in column named Date_time in a data-frame. The values(string type) present in that column is as:
                  "40 11-02-20 11:42:36"
I was trying to delete the characters until first space and trying to replace it with: "11-02-20 11:42:36". I was able to split the value but unable to rewrite it in the same cell of that column. Here is the code i have done so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('20-02-11.csv')

for i in dataset.itertuples():

    print(type(i.Date_time))
    str = i.Date_time
    str1 = str.split(None,1)[1]
    i.Date_time = str1
    print(str1)
    print(i.Date_time)
    break
```

and it shows AttributeError when i am trying to assign str1 to i.Date_time. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tuples that **itertuples()** returns, can/should not be used to set values in the original dataframe. They are copies not the actual data of the dataframe. You can try something like this:

```py
for i in range(len(dataset)):
    your_string = dataset.loc[i, "Date_time"]
    adjusted_string = your_string.split(None, 1)[1]
    dataset.loc[i, "Date_time"] = adjusted_string
```

This will use the actual data stored in the dataframe.

Using the `df.at()`-[function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```py
for i, row in dataset.iterrows():
    your_string = row.Date_time # or row['Date_time']
    adjusted_string = your_string.split(None, 1)[1]
    dataset.at[i,'Date_time'] = adjusted_string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the entire column at once. Starting with a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time': ['40 11-02-20 11:42:36', '31 11-02-20 11:42:36']})
print(df)
```

returns

```
date_time
0  40 11-02-20 11:42:36
1  31 11-02-20 11:42:36
```

You can remove the first characters and space like this:

```
df['date_time'] = [i[1+len(i.split(' ')[0]):] for i in df['date_time']]
print(df)
```

returns

```
            date_time
0  11-02-20 11:42:36
1  11-02-20 11:42:36
```